# best cross-platform mobile payment gateway/provider (Android, iPhone, WebOS etc.)

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, payment-gateway, payment

Which is the best cross-platform mobile payment solution?

I did work with Premium SMS gateways before, but premium sms is a bit tedious for customers in my opinion. If a customer wants to pay he needs to enter his phone number, then he receives some unique ID he has to enter into a form again for finalizing the payment.

So I wonder, if there are mobile payment providers offering something which is easy to use for customers, like in-app-payment, but cross-platform (iPhone, WebOS, Android etc.).

Best
Milanko

Answer (score 0):

For my mobile repair buisness i use pay anywhere app available for the android and iphone. Its completely free and you recieve a card reader that plugs directly into your device. The app and card reader are both free, they only charge a small fee per transaction. (1% per transaction) not too bad in my business!